# Accept more than one status code range with Alamofirie request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I would like to accept classic status code range (2XX) but also some extra error status code. So, how can i do this with the validate method of Alamofire Request?

Something like that:

```
Alamofire.request(self)
    .validate(statusCode: [ 200..<300 , 403 ])
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                ...
            case .Failure(let error):
                ...
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Alamofire accepts a `Range<Int>` parameter with acceptable codes. A range requires that all elements are consecutive, so you'll have to code your own validator. This should work:

```
.validate { _, response in
    let acceptableStatusCodes: [Range<Int>] = [200..<300, 403...403]
    if acceptableStatusCodes.map({$0.contains(response.statusCode)}).reduce(false, combine: {$0 || $1}) {
        return .Success
    } else {
        let failureReason = "Response status code was unacceptable: \(response.statusCode)"
        return .Failure(Error.errorWithCode(.StatusCodeValidationFailed, failureReason: failureReason))
    }
}
```

You can also declare it in a `Request` extension for better code reusability:

```
extension Request {
    func validateStatusCode() -> Request {
        return self.validate { _, response in
            let acceptableStatusCodes: [Range<Int>] = [200..<300, 403...403]
            if acceptableStatusCodes.map({$0.contains(response.statusCode)}).reduce(false, combine: {$0 || $1}) {
                return .Success
            } else {
                let failureReason = "Response status code was unacceptable: \(response.statusCode)"
                return .Failure(Error.errorWithCode(.StatusCodeValidationFailed, failureReason: failureReason))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Alamofire.request(self)
    .validateStatusCode()
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                ...
            case .Failure(let error):
                ...
            }
    })
```